# jQuery and my passed data to ajax is not at all what I intend

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am not sure what is going on. I've done exhausted searching for an answer. I thought it was processData but the ajax won't fire off in that case. I can't for the life of me figure out what is going on.

I am trying to send data via POST, ajax.

Because of how my data is set up, in page, I can actually create a hash and push it into an array. So I have something like.

The data I am forming looks like this:

in my init func, I set up some vars.

```
this.dataHolder = [];
```

in a method in my plugin:

```
            _acceptData:function(){
                var item = {};
                item[this.schema.itemId] =
                          {
                             "Color" : this.schema.color,
                             "Size" : this.schema.size,
                              "Cost"    : this.schema.cost

                          }
               return item;
            },
```

basically I have some other methods and such, but the jist is that that data structure above gets put into: this.dataHolder

when I dump the data, looks like it should. Various console.logs thruout the code shows me the data is well formed etc.. BUT when I pass it into the ajax data.. it does wonky things.

When I have my ajax.. ala:

```
 var self = this;
.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data : {matchedItems : self.dataHolder},
  dataType: json,
  url : /some/path/
```

I tried soo many different things, and in all cases the data is either undefined (when I Post it) OR its in a weird format, like: (in logs)

```
  $VAR1 = {

      'matchedItems[0][itemid1][Color]' => 'Blue',
      'matchedItems[0][itemid1][Size]' => '11',
      'matchedItems[0][itemid1][Cost]' => '33.90',
      'matchedItems[1][itemid2][Color][]' => 'Silver',
      'matchedItems[1][itemid2][Size]' => '13',
      'matchedItems[1][itemid2][Cost]' => '44',
      'matchedItems[2][itemid3][Color][]' => 'Red',
      'matchedItems[2][itemid3][Size]' => '9',
      'matchedItems[2][itemid3][Cost]' => '23'
    };
```

or different permutations

```
data : MatchedItems : {self.dataHolder}
```

or

```
data : {MatchedItems : {self.dataHolder}}
```

etc.. doesn't matter, the POST always gets some really odd formatting.

This is the way it should look when I send it and how they receive it.

```
matchedIeds = {
          itemId1 :
            {
              Color : Red,
              Size : 11,
              Cost    : 44
            },
          itemId2 :
            {
              Color : Blue,
              Size : 8,
              Cost    : 12
            },
          itemId3 :
            {
              Color : Blue,
              Size : 19,
              Cost    : 88.09
            }
          }
```

I mean, I am setting up my data like that so I can't see what is wrong.

Note: I tried processData : false, but that didn't help at all.

**EDIT:**
Here is the code console.log'd out write before I pass it into the .ajax method.
**Console.log**

```
[Object { itemid1={...}}, Object { itemid2={...}}, Object { itemid3={...}}]
```

**Here it is in the params of the post:**
    jquery.js (line 641)
POST http://www.myurl/to/test

200 OK
        79ms
jquery.js (line 7829)

HeadersPostResponseJSONCookies

```
Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
undefined   undefined
undefined   undefined
undefined   undefined
```

Comment: Can you set-up a demo on jsFiddle so we can see the entire code, or at least the related parts? Explaining it in this manner makes it more confusing, especially when there are a lot if "in-between explanations".

Comment: look at the actual request in a browser console to see what is being sent. The params tab in the request in console will tell you a lot. WHere does this come from `$VAR1 = { 'matchedItems[0][itemid1][Color]' => 'Blue'`  it looks like a mix of php and javascript?

Comment: that $VAR is the error_log from the perl controller. The params tab shows me the "junked up look". So yeah, that is messed up. BUT when I console.log the data prior to the .ajax call, it looks good. So there is something in how that data is getting converted.

Comment: Try : `data : {matchedItems : $.param(self.dataHolder)},`

Comment: Wait a minute? Is that an array containing an array containing an object with quoted keys, which you stick in an object, and then try to send as a POST request ?

Comment: well wait.I edited it. Its just an array of hashes. . How would you suggest I send it. That is what the perl controller is expecting.. a certain format. I am trying to match it on the front side to send, but apparently it isn't converting correctly. NOTE: I tried your suggestion, gave me undefines'

Comment: After some more investigation, I think JSON.stringfiy() is my solution. Problem is, its a third party include. Not sure that is feasible, and its built into new browsers.. but alas, I have to support older browsers. arghh.

Comment: use Crockford's json2.js as fallback. It is the same set of functions that were incorporated into browsers

Comment: simple debugging exercise in AJAX... send data to file that simply dumps the whole POST back to client. Use browser console to inspect data sent/received

Comment: Yeah, I looked into json2.js - but since we already use prototype in addition to jQuery - I can just use prototypes builtin version.. ala. Object.toJSON(). I'll use that since its already in play. Don't want to introduce another script include into the site. Thanks though. Appreciate your comments.